# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'double' while calling a method?

Tags: c#

```
public static void GetSales(string monthArray, double monthlySales )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Monthly Sales for {0}", monthArray[i]);
        monthlySales[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    string[] monthArray =new string[12] {"January", "FEBRUARY","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","Novemember","December"};
    double[] monthlySales= new double[12];
    GetSales(monthArray[0],monthlySales[0]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'n not sure why i'm getting this error in the GetSales method for the double monthlySales[] Any help would be great Thanks.

Comment: Your argument is `double monthlySales` not `double monthlySales[]`.  You forgot the `[]`.

Comment: Next stop will be: How to check if the user types a valid numeric value?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a double to your `GetSales` method instead of the array and as such there is nothing to index.  You should pass the entire array.

```
GetSales(monthArray[0], monthlySales);

public static void GetSales(string monthArray, double[] monthlySales )
```

Answer (score 1):

You've become confused with the way arrays work.

You're passing this: `string monthArray, double monthlySales`, but inside your method, you're treating them as arrays. `monthArray[i]` *happens* to work, because a `string` just so happens to be a collection of `chars`, so `monthArray[0]` is really returning the first letter of the month, not the first month.

Try this:

```
public static void GetSales(string[] monthArray, double[] monthlySales )
                           //     ^^ changed here      ^^
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Monthly Sales for {0}", monthArray[i]);

       monthlySales[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string[] monthArray =new string[12] {"January", "FEBRUARY","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","Novemember","December"};
    double[] monthlySales= new double[12];
    GetSales(monthArray, monthlySales);
    //         ^^ changed here  ^^
    Console.ReadLine();
}//main
```

Comment: That worked and i get it now that I'm able to step through it and see what it's doing. Thank you for the quick help.